# How can I put the messages from my bot in black boxes on Discord?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, discord, discord.py

I want my bot to output the text of normal commands in black boxes like in this help command:

[image: Black Boxes]

Right now, this is my output:

[image: Code of my output]

Comment: https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/210298617-Markdown-Text-101-Chat-Formatting-Bold-Italic-Underline-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are code blocks, and as [CDJB linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60003245/how-can-i-put-the-messages-from-my-not-in-black-boxes-in-discord-solved#comment106117026_60003245), you can find the markdown for them at https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/210298617-Markdown-Text-101-Chat-Formatting-Bold-Italic-Underline-.